# Configuring keycloak(OpenId) with Apache NiFi for user management

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, apache-nifi

Is there any way to configure Keycloak for Apache NiFi with OIDC protocol for authentication? I have found [link](https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/02/17/apache-nifi-saml-keycloak) for SAML protocol. But not sure how to use the same with OpenID protocol. Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this help? https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/03/apache-nifi-openid-connect